# How to secure images in wordpress/woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, security, woocommerce, sftp

For example I have an online store for mugs with images. Users can upload their image and purchase a mug with their image (without registration). The image needs to be stored securely, so no other party can access it through directories, only the admins can.

Any tips how to achieve this?

Comment: If you are using a form plugin that allow file uploads, there will be no security problems.

Comment: I am using own upload method. Do you know how to hide directories or ask password if you enter a directory?